# How to do multiple lines on Tabbed Panel tabs?

Tags: xpages, xpinc

Is there a way to show multiple lines on the default Tabbed Panel tabs? It has to be the stock, not Extlib, Tabbed Panel as this is for an 8.53 XPiNC application and having ExtLib installed cannot be guaranteed.

I need a way to show a title and below that some additional text also on the same tab. Putting on the same lines makes the tabs to wide, especially when I have four or five of them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jeremy: the question is clear.  In an XPiNC app on 8.5.3 can the standard tab pane label have more than one line and a image?

Comment: @stwissel The question was edited.

Comment: Even if I hadn't edited it Jeremy, anyone who knows anything about XPages would have understood it. I edited it to make you happy :)

Answer (score 1):

I would still go for the Dojo tabbed panel. The code is there even without Extlib. It is just a little more work si ce you have to sprinkle the html needed into your forms. There you have ultimate flexibility.